# My Browser is throwing an error when i am trying to get to my webpage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
```

This the the type of error which I am getting..

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code and detail as to what you are trying to achieve? Also, you can use block code using between two of ``` these to make it more easily readable.

Comment: I installed NodeJS and was willing to use my system as a server for my Frontend data I installed express and used hooks to target whatever is written in the form and stored it in the list. but when I started executing my  its throws an error **cannot read the property prototype of undefined**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.